# resizing the second child view controllers view in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cordova, uiviewcontroller

I am doing a PhoneGap iPad application. In this I had added a HybridPage (which contains webView) as a child view controller and then after that screen I am adding a New Controller (also removed the hybridPage from ParentViewController) which contains Native Controller and again same instance of HybridPage Controller (added two controllers as childs).

Here My Native Controller size is (320,704) and Hybrid Controller size is (702,704).

Now the problem is I am not able to interact with Half frame of Hybrid controller from right side (320 width from the end of contentoffset of the view).

I have given the two viewControllers frames even though  I am not able to interact with some rect of Hybrid controller.

- (void)setDashboardRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController

{

```
    if ([[self childViewControllers] containsObject:[MCIPadRootViewController getIPadRootViewController].mcWebViewController])

{

    [[MCIPadRootViewController getIPadRootViewController] removeMCWebViewController];

}

[self addChildViewController:self.dashboardViewController];

[self.dashboardContainerView addSubview:self.dashboardViewController.view];

if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[MCLoginFlowWebViewController class]])

{

    [self addChildViewController:[MCIPadRootViewController getIPadRootViewController].mcWebViewController];

    [MCIPadRootViewController getIPadRootViewController].mcWebViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mcWebViewContainerView.frame.size.width, self.mcWebViewContainerView.frame.size.height);

    [self.mcWebViewContainerView addSubview:[MCIPadRootViewController getIPadRootViewController].mcWebViewController.view];

}
```

}

Where can i set Child ViewController's Frame. Here i had set the viewcontroller's view frame but it is not effecting.
Could anybody help me to get out from this issue.

Please find the Screen shot for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with my Own solution.

The problem is my application opens in Landscape mode So i converted my view frame to bounds.

```
[[[self recurringListController] view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
```

Using the above method I overcome my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would typically set the frame of a child view controller's view in 2 places.

1. Right before you add it to the parent. Search for a call to addChildViewController: in the parent view controller. Set frame right before that call (there may be 2 calls to addChildViewController:).
2. If the size changes due to rotation you'll need to reset the frame of the child view controller's view in the parent view controller's viewWillLayoutSubviews: method.

Here's an example from a custom split view controller.

Notice the 2 places where where #1 is set.

```
- (void)setMasterViewController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    if (!_masterViewController) {
        // Add the new controller
        controller.view.frame = self.masterView.bounds;
        [self addChildViewController:controller];
        [self.masterView addSubview:controller.view];
        [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        _masterViewController = controller;
    } 
    else if (_masterViewController != controller) {
        // Transition from the old to new controller
        controller.view.frame = self.masterView.bounds;
        [_masterViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [self addChildViewController:controller];
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self transitionFromViewController:_masterViewController 
                          toViewController:controller 
                                  duration:0.0
                                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                                animations:^{} 
                                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                                    [_masterViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                                    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                                    _masterViewController = controller;
                                }
         ];

    } 
}
```

Here is where #2 is set:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
    float contentWidth = contentFrame.size.width;

    CGRect masterRect = contentFrame;
    CGRect detailRect = contentFrame;
    CGRect dividerRect = contentFrame;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
        masterRect.size.width = DEFAULT_SPLIT_POSITION;
        detailRect.origin.x = DEFAULT_SPLIT_POSITION + DEFAULT_DIVIDER_WIDTH;
        detailRect.size.width = contentWidth - (DEFAULT_SPLIT_POSITION + DEFAULT_DIVIDER_WIDTH);
        dividerRect.size.width = DEFAULT_DIVIDER_WIDTH;
        dividerRect.origin.x = DEFAULT_SPLIT_POSITION;
    }
    else {
        masterRect.size.width = contentWidth;
        detailRect.origin.x = contentWidth;
        dividerRect.origin.x = contentWidth;
    }

    self.masterView.frame = masterRect;
    self.detailView.frame = detailRect;
    self.dividerView.frame = dividerRect;
}
```

**[Edited]**

So can you update your code with the following so that you call all of the view container containment methods are used and called in the correct order.

```
[MCIPadRootViewController getIPadRootViewController].mcWebViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mcWebViewContainerView.frame.size.width, self.mcWebViewContainerView.frame.size.height);
[self addChildViewController:[MCIPadRootViewController getIPadRootViewController].mcWebViewController];
[self.mcWebViewContainerView addSubview:[MCIPadRootViewController getIPadRootViewController].mcWebViewController.view];
[controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Also I don't think your CGRectMake is correct. You normally wouldn't reference the view's frame, you would reference the parent view's bounds. Try setting it like this and see if it helps. That will have it fill the parent view but you can also tweak it.

```
[MCIPadRootViewController getIPadRootViewController].mcWebViewController.view.frame = self.mcWebViewContainerView.bounds;
```

Comment: Thanks For your help Jesse, But still my issue is not resolved. Also I  was just added a screenshot for you to understand my issue. While debugging I just find the orientation issue, i.e. DetailView (Hybrid) frame is landscape(1024,768) and MasterView is portrait (768,1024).

Comment: There are more steps necessary when adding a child view controller. That may be your issue. I see that you're only calling addChildViewController:. That's not enough on its own. Read the 'Implementing a Container View Controller' section of the UIViewController documentation. You can reference my code sample #1 for the other methods that need to be called.

Comment: firstly My app have a Hybrid Page (login) which is having full frame size (1024, 768) and then after that Hybrid page i am using same instance of hybrid page in Dashboard View which is having both Native and Hybrid Pages. and also My app doesn't supports Portrait. Thanks for your valuable suggestion Jesse

Comment: This issue has raised due to this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038653/phonegap-ios-app-loads-in-landscape-mode-in-different-orientation
Problem is My view Status bar is in landscape mode but the view frame in viewdidappear is returning portrait frame (768,1024).